# SIP servlets, chatserver

Tags: java, servlets, sip

I'm trying to get a SIP servlet chat server working, [together with the textclient found here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/dev2arch/2007/10/introduction-jain-sip.html).

When I use 2 clients to send messages to eachother (peer to peer), everything goes well. But when I use one or more clients together with my server, I have to wait exactly 32 seconds before the server picks up any new messages in the `doMessage()` method.
I'm using Netbeans together with Sailfin as my SIP server. Is there some kind of limitation or configurable delay or timeout between requests or responses in Sailfin I'm looking over?

I can post the server code, if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, if someone ever encounters the same problem, i found this is a bug in the textclient against the following section 8.1.1.7 of RFC 3261.

> The branch parameter value MUST be
>   unique across space and time for all
>   requests sent by the UA.  The
>   exceptions to this rule are CANCEL and
>   ACK for non-2xx responses.  As
>   discussed below, a CANCEL request will
>   have the same value of the branch
>   parameter as the request it cancels. 
>   As discussed in Section 17.1.1.3, an
>   ACK for a non-2xx response will also
>   have the same branch ID as the INVITE
>   whose response it acknowledges.
>
> The uniqueness property of the branch
>   ID parameter, to facilitate its use as
>   a transaction ID, was not part of RFC
>   2543.
>
> The branch ID inserted by an element
>   compliant with this specification MUST
>   always begin with the characters
>   "z9hG4bK".

The following line in SipLayer.java

```
ViaHeader viaHeader = headerFactory.createViaHeader(getHost(),
getPort(), "udp", "branch1");
```

Will create every message with the "branch1" parameter. Making this parameter unique fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code of the server, i'll try to make a wireshark trace later.

```
public class ChatroomSipServlet extends SipServlet {

    public final static String USER_LIST = "userList";

    public final static String CHATROOM_SERVER_NAME = "chatroomservername";

    public String serverAddress;
    public SipFactory factory;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
        super.init(servletConfig);
        System.out.println("Chatroom sip servlet is gestart!");
        try {
            factory = (SipFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.sip.SipFactory");
            System.out.println("Sip Factory: " + factory);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException("Factory probleem!", e);
        }
        getServletContext().setAttribute(USER_LIST, new ArrayList<String>());
        serverAddress = getServletConfig().getInitParameter(CHATROOM_SERVER_NAME);
        System.out.println("serverAddress is: " + serverAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            sendToAll(serverAddress, "Server sluit af!");
        } catch (Throwable e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.destroy();
    }

    protected void doMessage(SipServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println(getDateTime() + " Bericht ontvangen");

        request.createResponse(SipServletResponse.SC_OK).send();

        String message = request.getContent().toString();
        String from = ((SipURI) request.getFrom().getURI()).toString();

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("/quit")) {
            sendToUser(from, "Bye");
            removeUser(from);
            return;
        }

        if (!containsUser(from)) {
            sendToUser(from, "Welkom in de chatroom. Typ '/quit' om af te sluiten.");
            addUser(from);
        }

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("/who")) {
            String users = "Lijst van de gebruikers:\n";
            List<String> list = (List<String>) getServletContext().getAttribute(USER_LIST);
            for (String user : list) {
                users += user + "\n";
            }
            sendToUser(from, users);
            return;
        }

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("/join")) {
            return;
        }

        sendToAll(from, message);
    }

    protected void doErrorResponse(SipServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

//      String receiver = response.getTo().toString();
        String receiver = ((SipURI) response.getTo().getURI()).toString();
        System.out.println(getDateTime() + " Errorresponse voor " + receiver);
        removeUser(receiver);
    }

    protected void doSuccessResponse(SipServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getApplicationSession().invalidate();
    }

    private void sendToAll(String from, String message) throws ServletParseException, IOException {

        List<String> list = (List<String>) getServletContext().getAttribute(USER_LIST);
        for (String user : list) {
            SipApplicationSession session = factory.createApplicationSession();
            System.out.println(getDateTime() + " Session created voor " + user);
            SipServletRequest request = factory.createRequest(session, "MESSAGE", serverAddress, user);
            String msg = from + " stuurt: \n" + message;
            request.setContent(msg.getBytes(), "text/plain");
            request.send();
        }
    }

    private void sendToUser(String to, String message) throws ServletParseException, IOException {

        SipApplicationSession session = factory.createApplicationSession();
        SipServletRequest request = factory.createRequest(session, "MESSAGE", serverAddress, to);
        request.setContent(message.getBytes(), "text/plain");
        request.send();
    }

    private boolean containsUser(String from) {
        List<String> list = (List<String>) getServletContext().getAttribute(USER_LIST);
        return list.contains(from);
    }

    private void addUser(String from) {
        List<String> list = (List<String>) getServletContext().getAttribute(USER_LIST);
        list.add(from);
    }

    private void removeUser(String from) {
        System.out.println(getDateTime() + " " + from + " wordt verwijderd uit de lijst.");
        List<String> list = (List<String>) getServletContext().getAttribute(USER_LIST);
        list.remove(from);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doRegister(SipServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Register request ontvangen: " + req.getTo());
        int response = SipServletResponse.SC_OK;
        SipServletResponse resp = req.createResponse(response);
        resp.send();
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("[" + "HH:mm:ss" + "]");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

And the sip.xml

```
<sip-app>
    <app-name>sip.chatvoorbeeld.ChatServer</app-name>
    <display-name>Chatroom Sip Servlet</display-name>
    <description>Chatroom Sip Servlet</description>

    <servlet-selection>
        <main-servlet>
            ChatroomSipServlet
        </main-servlet>
    </servlet-selection>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ChatroomSipServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>ChatroomSipServlet</display-name>
        <description>Chatroom SIP servlet</description>
        <servlet-class>
            sip.chatvoorbeeld.ChatroomSipServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>chatroomservername</param-name>
            <param-value>sip:chatserver@192.168.56.1:5060</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</sip-app>
```

I also tried an empty servlet, just with a `doMessage()` method that just prints out "message received". Same 32 seconds delay...

Wireshark gives me:

I send the message "test" to the server:

```
MESSAGE sip:chatserver@192.168.56.1:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Call-ID: aba00c2646a9b4e6df3b15df19dbf58d@192.168.56.101
CSeq: 1 MESSAGE
From: "bobby" <sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095>;tag=textclientv1.0
To: "chatserver" <sip:chatserver@192.168.56.1:5060>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.56.101:5095;branch=branch1
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: "bobby" <sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095>
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 4

test
```

Server sends back:

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
To: "chatserver"<sip:chatserver@192.168.56.1:5060>;tag=g9vdns7u-e
Cseq: 1 MESSAGE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.56.101:5095;branch=branch1
From: "bobby"<sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095>;tag=textclientv1.0
Call-Id: aba00c2646a9b4e6df3b15df19dbf58d@192.168.56.101
Server: Glassfish_SIP_2.0.0

MESSAGE sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095 SIP/2.0
Max-Forwards: 69
Content-Length: 43
To: <sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095>
Cseq: 1 MESSAGE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.56.1:5060;branch=z9hG4bKdaacb7673c871796474ca951221a6643db6c
Content-Type: text/plain
Call-Id: 192.168.56.1_11_6595680936174578736
From: <sip:chatserver@192.168.56.1:5060>;tag=g9vdns7u-g

sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095 stuurt: 
test
```

Then my client again answers with an OK:

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK
To: <sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095>;tag=888
CSeq: 1 MESSAGE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.56.1:5060;branch=z9hG4bKdaacb7673c871796474ca951221a6643db6c;received=192.168.56.1
Call-ID: 192.168.56.1_11_6595680936174578736
From: <sip:chatserver@192.168.56.1:5060>;tag=g9vdns7u-g
Content-Length: 0
```

So far so good, everything works well.
But now I send a second message to the server "test2" and I get this:

Client to server:

```
MESSAGE sip:chatserver@192.168.56.1:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 95ad65365378b9b6b5bd7ad3629f7b02@192.168.56.101
CSeq: 1 MESSAGE
From: "bobby" <sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095>;tag=textclientv1.0
To: "chatserver" <sip:chatserver@192.168.56.1:5060>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.56.101:5095;branch=branch1
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: "bobby" <sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095>
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 5

test2
```

Then the server does respond with:

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
To: "chatserver"<sip:chatserver@192.168.56.1:5060>;tag=g9vdns7u-e
Cseq: 1 MESSAGE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.56.101:5095;branch=branch1
From: "bobby"<sip:bobby@192.168.56.101:5095>;tag=textclientv1.0
Call-Id: aba00c2646a9b4e6df3b15df19dbf58d@192.168.56.101
Server: Glassfish_SIP_2.0.0
```

But then the communication stops... I get a 200 OK, but the `println()` in my `doMessage()` method is not passed.

Answer (score 1):

32 seconds is the normal timeout for transactions (denoted 64*T1 in RFC3261, where the default for T1 is 500ms.)

I have no direct idea for a solution to your problem, except that the timeout is very likely NOT a misconfiguration in SailFin. So please provide a wireshark trace and the server code!