# how to run my sip servlet in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, sip-server

I am new in SIP server development. I read a lot about sipservlet and sailfin like

[SIP servlets, chatserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927604/sip-servlets-chatserver)

If I write that code in netbeans I cannot right click on the sip servlet and click run as it told me it doesnot contain main method or it is not in web.xml.

I am confused:

1- Why I need sailfin to run my sip application

2- Can I run my sipservlet in netbeans like httpservlet

3- How I can register my servlet with any ip.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sailfin has been killed by Oracle, please checkout Mobicents instead http://dzone.com/links/mobicents_sip_servlets_200final_with_support_for.html